# How to pass a hyperlink value to PHP Dropdown value for display

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Im Setting up a classroom manager system for my school assignment and was basically wondering if it is possible to pass a href value or id into an   Drop Down menu. My intent of this is so when the link is clicked that students name and id will be passed through into the dropdown option to automatically select the students name ready to go to insert/add/ or delete a students behaviour notes the next step will be enable the user to write about the student before submitting the form. If it is possible i would like to do it in the same page. I hope this makes sense to someone out there thanks in advance :)

Ive just been doing some dummy testing trying different things out. nothing i have done has worked

```
$student_query "//SQL Statement";

$class_result = mysqli_query($conn, $student_query);

while($sub_row = mysqli_fetch_array($class_result)){
```

This is the HREF - Please note it is a fetch Assoc cycle so it displays the list of names of each students in a class. I know my naming conventions are not perfect so sorry in advance :( and its probably more elements than i need there

```
<a href"?id='.$product_id.'" value="'.$sub_row["STUDENT_ID"].'" type="button" data-toggle="modal" class="pointer" data-target="#myModal" value="'.$sub_row["student"].'">'.$sub_row["student"].'</a>            
// This is for the dropdown

<label>Select Student: </label>
<select name="class">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select your class</option>
<?php
```

The code below in sql is my long and absurd way of gettin the class, the student and student id from database.

I want to move same student id into the code below to get the display the student first who was selected

```
$tab_query = ("SELECT DISTINCT s.STUDENT_ID, sc.STUDENT_CLASS_ID, 
                c.CLASS,s.STUDENT_CODE, 
                concat(s.NAME_FIRST,' ',s.NAME_LAST) AS student 
            FROM  student_class_tbl AS sc 
                JOIN class_tbl as t ON sc.CLASS_ID = t.CLASS_ID  
                JOIN c AS C ON t.CLASS_NAME = C.C_ID  
                JOIN student_tbl AS s ON sc.STUDENT_ID = s.STUDENT_ID  
                JOIN teacher_tbl AS f ON t.CLASS_TEACHER = f.TEACHER_ID 
            WHERE f.USERNAME = '$myusername' 
            ORDER BY student") ;
//$tab_query = "SELECT C_ID, CLASS FROM c ORDER by class";
$tab_result = mysqli_query($conn, $tab_query);

while ($rows = $tab_result->fetch_assoc())  {
    $NAME = $rows['student'];
    $ID = $rows['STUDENT_ID'];
    $class = $rows['CLASS'];
    echo "<option class='form-control'  value='$ID'>$NAME : $class </option>";      
}
?>
</select>
```

The results i am trying to get is if if the user selects from a list of students

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

And the teacher clicks on E

I want that value to be passed through so the very first thing the dropdown menu displays is

```
E
```

Preferabbly done on same PHP page

Comment: For your assignment, are you authorised to use javascript?

Comment: By the way, your code seems a little confused...you have a label saying "select student", which is followed by a dropdownlist saying "select your class"...

Comment: Anyway it's unclear...is the `<a href` inside the same page as the `<select`? If so then it seems you already know the student ID via `$sub_row["STUDENT_ID"]`. If they're not, then you need to include the student ID on the querystring of the URL, e.g. `<a href="?id='.$product_id.'&studentID='.$sub_row["STUDENT_ID"].'"` ...and then when the link is clicked, the student ID will be available to the target PHP script as `$_GET["studentID"]` (BTW your href had a typo, the `=` was missing...I added it in my example here)

Comment: Yes i am able to use javascript - Toni van De Voorde

Comment: ADyson- i am aware there are some current errors with this code atm this is just a duplicate file of another in which i was playing around with different variables and different options